# "python3 -V" and "python -V" both display Python 2.7.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, version

For some reason "python3 -V" uses the Python 2.7.6 version, which is the older version that I had prior to upgrading to Python 3.4.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you on?

If on linux, try typing

```
$ ll /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan  3 20:38 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4*
```

If it shows python3 is linked to something other than python3+ then you will need to fix the link.

Comment: I'm getting the correct input:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Feb 23  2015 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4*`

but running the command "python3" in the terminal boots up python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your python3 alias is pointing to python2.7 by mistake. What does

`$ which python3`
return? If it's pointing to python2.7 and you want to correct it, use

`$ ln -s python3-path python3alias-path`
Might need `sudo`

Comment: `which python3` correctly returns `/usr/bin/python3`, but the python3 command in the terminal still boots up python 2.7.6.

I attempted to remove any incorrect alias between `python` and `python3` to no avail, however.

Comment: What happens if you run the python3 executable directly? `$ /usr/bin/python3` Does it go into python3.4 correctly?

Comment: running `$ /usr/bin/python3` opens up python 2.7.6